# Send email using Google API with only access token

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to send an email through Google API without the unnecessary OAUTH2 parameters. I only have the access_token and the refresh_token of that user.

How can I send an email through Gmail API through a basic POST request in NodeJS, with Request npm plugin?

Comment: How can I generate Access_token for the user without massive hassles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

abraham is correct, but I just thought I'd give you an example.

```
var request = require('request');

server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);

  // Base64-encode the mail and make it URL-safe 
  // (replace all "+" with "-" and all "/" with "_")
  var encodedMail = new Buffer(
        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" +
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" +
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n" +
        "to: reciever@gmail.com\n" +
        "from: sender@gmail.com\n" +
        "subject: Subject Text\n\n" +

        "The actual message text goes here"
  ).toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

  request({
      method: "POST",
      uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer 'access_token'",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "raw": encodedMail
      })
    },
    function(err, response, body) {
      if(err){
        console.log(err); // Failure
      } else {
        console.log(body); // Success!
      }
    });
});
```

**Don't forget to change the reciever and sender email address for the example to work.**

Comment: This answer solved my issue with invalid credentials.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ShashidharGr Awesome :) Glad I could help!

Comment: If I use `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send` I am receiving the error
Media type 'application/json' is not supported. Valid media types: [message/rfc822].
I need to send an email with attachments

Answer (score 4):

There are [two methods](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/query-parameters) for attaching OAuth2 access_tokens to a Google API request.

- Using the access_token query parameter like this: `?access_token=oauth2-token`
- Using the HTTP Authorization header like this: `Authorization: Bearer oauth2-token`

The second one is prefered for POST requests so the raw HTTP request for sending an email would look something like this.

```
POST /gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer oauth2Token
{"raw":"encodedMessage"}
```

Comment: What is the difference between using Bearer or OAuth in Authorization header? Example: `'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + account.access_token,

Comment: `Authorization: Bearer ...` is [OAuth 2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-7.1), `Authorization: OAauth ...` is [OAuth 1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849#section-3.5.1). Although I'm sure there are other uses for both.