# send email via google http rest api

Tags: node.js, email, google-api, http-post, gmail-api

I am trying to send email from NodeJS running on a Linux server to Google Gmail RESR HTTP API. Not using libraries, just sending `https`. I have figured out the OAuth part, have an access token and get responses from google.  But I cannot get past various error messages.  I have posted the code below. It is not obvious but `EmailSend()` is called after I get the access token from google, so yeah it is being called.

```
var emailStr = new Buffer(
      "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" +
      "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" +
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n" +
      "to: SOMEONE@gmail.com\n" +
      "from: SOMEONEELSE@MYDOMAIN.com\n" +
      "subject: Subject Text\n\n" +

      "The actual message text goes here"
).toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
//var emailBase64UrlSafe = Rtrim( emailStr, '=' );
//var emailBase64UrlSafe = JsStrToUrlSafe ( emailStr );
var emailBase64UrlSafe = emailStr;

var http = require('https');
function EmailSend() {
  
  var post_data = emailBase64UrlSafe;
  var post_options = {
      hostname: 'www.googleapis.com',
      port: '443',
      path: '/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer '+googleAccessKey['access_token'],
        "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      },
  };
  console.log( post_options );

  var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
      });
  });
  post_req.write(JSON.stringify({ "raw": emailBase64UrlSafe }));
  post_req.end();
}; /* end EmailSend() */
```

> ```
> Response: {
> ```

```
"error": {
 "errors": [
  {
   "domain": "global",
   "reason": "failedPrecondition",
   "message": "Bad Request"
  }
 ],
 "code": 400,
 "message": "Bad Request"
}
```

Resources used:

1. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#appendix-A
2. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
3. https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback
4. [Send email using Google API with only access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504289/send-email-using-google-api-with-only-access-token?rq=1)

Comment: I could not get these resources into the post without messing up the formatting.  So here they are. 1. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#appendix-A
2. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
3. https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback
4. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504289/send-email-using-google-api-with-only-access-token?rq=1

Comment: Are you doing domain wide delegation and impersonating the user for your service account? check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation otherwise it will throw this error.

Comment: Look at the documentation, you need to post an object, of which the message is just a part: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried it for myself, and it worked!

```
var http = require('https');

var mail = new Buffer(
    "From: example@gmail.com\n" +
    "To: example@gmail.com\n" +
    "Subject: Subject Text\n\n" +

    "Message text"
).toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');


var post_options = {
  hostname: 'www.googleapis.com',
  port: '443',
  path: '/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": 'Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>',
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  }
};

var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
  });
});

post_req.write(JSON.stringify({ "raw": mail }));
post_req.end();
```