# Sending an email with Gmail's API using only a token?

Tags: angularjs, api, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to using Google's API to send an email. I have a web application powered by AngularJS where the user signs in with their google account (via passport.js) using oauth2. A new access token is written to their account on my database. Their google user ID is also written to their account. I'd like the user to be able to send an email via an HTTP request using simply their user Id and access token. I'm using Postman to make some test requests, but I keep getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
        "message": "Insufficient Permission"
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
  }
}
```

I'm using the following link to make a POST request:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/106xxxxxxxxxxx/messages/send
```

In my header, I have:

```
Authorization: Bearer yaxx._wxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: application/json
```

My body:

```
{
 "raw": "test"
}
```

I've had some of the emails intermittently come in using this method, but I can't seem to recreate a successful request with certainty. I'm a little confused by Google's documentation. Do I need to explicitly grant access as seen in the example at the bottom of [this page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `access token` you mentioned needs to be present in the `POST`-request you send the mail with. The [Oauth2](http://oauth.net/2/)-procotol dictates that you need to either pass along a header `Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>`, or a parameter `access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>`.

The value of `raw` also needs to be a valid [base64-encoded rfc822](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504289/send-email-using-google-api-with-only-access-token/29515412#29515412) mail. An example in JavaScript could look like the following:

```
// Base64-encode the mail and make it URL-safe 
// (replace all "+" with "-" and all "/" with "_")
var encodedMail = btoa(
      "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" +
      "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" +
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n" +
      "Subject: Subject of the mail\n" +
      "From: sender@gmail.com\n" +
      "To: reciever@gmail.com\n\n" +

      "This is where the mail text will go"
    ).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
```

This will result in a string that you use as the `raw` in the request body.

A request in Postman would then look like the following:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>

{ // The encoded mail from the example above.
 "raw": "Q29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L3BsYWluOyBjaGFyc2V0PSJVVEYtOCIKTUlNRS1WZXJzaW9uOiAxLjAKQ29udGVudC1UcmFuc2Zlci1FbmNvZGluZzogN2JpdApTdWJqZWN0OiBTdWJqZWN0IG9mIHRoZSBtYWlsCkZyb206IHNlbmRlckBnbWFpbC5jb20KVG86IHJlY2lldmVyQGdtYWlsLmNvbQoKVGhpcyBpcyB3aGVyZSB0aGUgbWFpbCB0ZXh0IHdpbGwgZ28="
}
```

You also need to supply the `Content-Type`-header with the value of `application/json`. Note that you don't have to use a userId. Supplying `me` will make Google use the user associated with the supplied access token automatically.

Also make sure you asked for a sufficient permission `scope` with Passport. `https://mail.google.com/` will work.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the same error response. Here's a copy of my Postman HTTP request. `POST /gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?access_token=ya29.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c152b250-b38f-7280-6466-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

{
 "raw": "Q29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L3BsYWluOyBjaGFyc2V0PSJVVEYtOCIKTUlNRS1WZXJzaW9uOiAxLjAKQ29udGVudC1UcmFuc2Zlci1FbmNvZGluZzogN2JpdApTdWJqZWN0OiBTdWJqZWN0IG9mIHRoZSBtYWlsCkZyb206IHNlbmRlckBnbWFpbC5jb20KVG86IHJlY2lldmVyQGdtYWlsLmNvbQoKVGhpcyBpcyB3aGVyZSB0aGUgbWFpbCB0ZXh0IHdpbGwgZ28="
}`

Comment: @MikeJoyce Updated the answer :)

Comment: @Throlle : Your answer works for me but I would like to know From where did you get these different fields. I could not find it even in GMail API documentation

Comment: @WaelShowair The needed scope and that the raw-field has to be a url-safe base64-encoded string is stated in the gmail-api docs. Where the access token should be placed is a oauth2-convention. I found this out on various SO-questioms, though.

Comment: @Tholle : So this gets more at the heart of my question - can the scope be placed in the same HTTP request? Literally looking to be able to do this from postman without explicitly giving permission to an app.

Comment: @MikeJoyce Sadly, no. The scopes have to be given at the time you redirect the user to Google at the same time you give your ClientId and Secret. This will then give you a code you exchange for the access token used above. There is no way around this.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for your help! Accepting your answer because it will still help me implement what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @MikeJoyce Sweet :) Good luck!