# How to make a simple request with Postman, using api_key protocol?

Tags: gmail-api, postman

I need to use gmail API functions to send an email to somebody. 
I tried using tokens but i didn't manage, so now im trying with api_key.
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890508/sending-an-email-with-gmails-api-using-only-a-token). It stated that the `access token` needs to be present in the `POST`-request you send the mail with. The [Oauth2](https://oauth.net/2/)-procotol dictates that you need to either pass along a header `Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>`, or a parameter `access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>`.

Also make sure that you are [generating Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32127796/5832311) for the right app type. If you're using Postman to test Google oAuth 2 APIs, select Credentials->Add credentials->OAuth2.0 client ID->Web Application.